# Word 2010 doc skips pages

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

A Word document with 9 pages, 3 section brakes next page (no odd and even breaks used) and inserted page numbers shows the correct sequence of pages when moving thru the document.

When I change the page numbers in section 2 to start from 1 (Section 1 is only one page numbered with a roman numeral.) Then two strange things happen:

1. The sequence in the status bar goes from 1 to 3.
2. Page 2 disappeared (no text is missing) and my total number of pages reads 10 when i actually only have 9.

The first page has a table of contents. Page 2 is listed, but when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click the shortcut it goes to page 4?

Comment: Hard to grasp. Can you share the file? Using Dropbox or something?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a strange page numbering situation going on. If you edit page numbering enough, it will eventually barf on itself. The best solution that I can think of is to copy the text into a new document and start over. You can also try renumbering from the start, but I don't think you'll have any joy and this issue will haunt you if you ever need to edit the document in the future.